# Planned work until date in MS Project 2007

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2007

I want to know the Planned work until the status date to compare with the Earned work done to this date.

It is a value calculated in ARTEMIS , but I'm new in MS Project and I don't find it.

Like the PV and the EV but in days not in $.

The result is to know the % of work that should have been done at the status date.

It's the **sum of planned work at status date** that I'm searching for.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Finish Variance.  Open up the FV column.  As you progress your packages, if you have a healthy horizontal logic built in your schedule, you will accrue both favorable and unfavorable variances in your schedule network and the FV will show you in days what that variance is.  Positive numbers are unfavorable.

Comment: No. FV is about dates not work.I don't want to know if I'll finish faster. I want to know at a date if my earned work is more or less than my planned work.
Exemple : You have an activity of 10 work days and 20 days duration with one person.Assuming that she doing 0.5 work days per days.
At 5 days duration the person says she need only 5.5 work days to complete. Assuming she work 1.5, your duration is 5 and your earned work is (10/5.5*1.5)  2.72. I want the work that she was planned to do (10/20*5) 2.5 (this exemple is linear is't more complexe in real).Simply it's sum of planned work at a date

Comment: Use weighted milestones.  If you have something tangible that is developed somewhere during the duration of the package, you can calculate prospectively its weight based on planned work versus total work of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Project calculates earned value data as long as you have assigned costed resources, saved a baseline, updated the status date, and provided tracking.

Baseline cumulative work will also show you the planned work to date. (Project 2013)

Although it references Project 2007 - all still applies in later releases.  See:
http://www.tacticalprojectmanagement.com/how-to-calculate-earned-value-in-microsoft-project-2007/

Comment: I am not talking about $ here. We are not talking about the standard of PMI, because project I manage are long time project with a lot of people so $ is not enough. We need to track work too wich is not something commonly used.

Comment: If you assign the resources at $1 per hour then cost = work.  If you are using Project 2013, cumulative baseline work will show the planned work per day on the Project summary task line.

Comment: 1$ per hour is not = work because project are so big that their is ten's of people by activities and they are replaced during the projet so you could not know anymore how much a work unite worth. That's why we have separate $ and work.

Comment: Okay.  I'll say it once again :-) Add the Baseline Cumulative Work field to the Task Usage view -timescaled portion.  That will show the planned work (baseline work) for any day.

Comment: It's seems there is no Baseline cumulative work in 2007. Only Baseline work is there.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Sorry.  If earned value doesn't work, you'll need to export the data to Excel for analysis.  You might get close with the visual reports to export to an Excel Pivot table.

Comment: Yes this is the only way I find since a month. It do, but I'm happy to know that it will be available in 2013 ;) thanks Julie

Comment: You're welcome, Fred and thanks for the feedback.